# Google Tag manager conflict between 2 tags

Tags: google-ads-api, google-tag-manager

I try to use Google Tag Manager to:

1. Track conversions
2. Add users to remarketing list

Both are AdWords tags.

I have configured the tags in GTM, but only one of them is active when I perform a check with Tag Assistant. Initially I had only conversion tag and everything was ok. Then I added remarketing. It has the same Conversion ID, which as I googled is fine. Assistant only shows "Conversion Tag", but with no label, which I assume indicates that it is in fact remarketing tag, yet AdWords doesn't recognize it. Can I use both tags on the same and how?

Remarketing tag is recognized in debug, but conversion tag is not (before adding remarketing, conversion tag was working well).

Conversion:

[image]

Remarketing:

[image]

Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Is the GTM preview debugger showing all tags right?

Comment: I'm just starting with GTM, could you please tell me where can I find preview debugger?

Comment: you can find it top right corner, hidden behind drop down menu of a publish button, click that and check on site are they both active

Comment: @Ante I added more details in the question.

Comment: The screenshot you showed clearly indicate that basic event haven't been triggered. (it should always get triggered)

The problem can be that someone overwrote dataLayer variable. Is there any custom code on your side? (or inside other tags?)